# Is the interior of the difference of open sets non-empty?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$, $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be open sets such that $B \subsetneq A$. It's true that $ \text{int} (A-B) \neq \emptyset$?

I tried to assume it was empty, but I did not arrive at a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

False. Take $A=B_1(0,0)$ and $B=B_1(0,0)\setminus \{(0,0)\}$. Then $A\setminus B =\{(0,0)\}$ has empty interior.